# Rails: Masonry not working in production on Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, masonry

I have masonry on my rails app to style it. It is working just fine in development, but it is not working on production. I tried to figured out was going on for a while now.. but nothing worked.

gemfile:

```
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.0'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require magnific-popup
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

application. css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require magnific-popup
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I tried to precompile my assets on production:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

So as I said it is working perfectly in development but not on production.

I tried to look at my javascript console in chrome, but I can't find the problem, as I am not sure how to read it....

Any ideas?

Comment: is this with rails 4?

Comment: and just to check you have pushed to git and heroku since running the command?

Comment: Yeah of course I pushed to git and yes rails 4